# SQLite with readline support on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, console, packages, sqlite, readline

I had the `sqlite3` package installed on Ubuntu and there's no support for readline. That means there's no command history and those other nifty features readline gives you.

Is this a configuration or a packaging problem? Is there a different package archive somewhere that would give me readline support out of the box? Or else, how do I compile sqlite3 myself making sure it has readline support?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could always use rlwrap:

```
rlwrap sqlite3 database.db
```

FYI, I just checked my hardy heron install, and its sqlite3 does have readline support.

Comment: Didn't know about rlwrap. Really great, thanks! I'm using the sqlite3 package in Kubuntu Jaunty Jackalope and, for some reason, it didn't come with readline support.

Answer (score 23):

I add another answer because this is the first hit for "*ubuntu sqlite3 readline*" on google:

The android SDK installs its own version of the `sqlite3` binary. This binary does not provide `readline` support. If you added the Android SDK to your path this might make you think you have no `readline` support, in fact every Ubuntu package is compiled with `readline` support.

Also see this [Ubuntu Bug Report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sqlite3/+bug/606970) which describes the same situation.

Comment: Anaconda does the same thing. Argh! /usr/bin/sqlite3 works fine.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. My Android SDK was hiding my /usr/bin/sqlite3 application.

Comment: This was the case on my macOS High Sierra as well. You can check by running `which sqlite3`.

Comment: +1, it was my issue as well, I had `$ANDROID_HOME/Sdk/platform-tools` after `$PATH`, but I just didn't install sqlite3. And I found this thread using exactly the same search phrase.

Answer (score 6):

1. Download the zip file containing C source code from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html (sqlite-amalgamation-nnnnnnn.zip)
2. Unzip it to get shell.c, sqlite3.c, and the .h files.
3. If not already installed, install libreadline and libncurses. On Ubuntu Linux, install by running the command below:

   sudo apt install libreadline-dev libncurses-dev
4. Run the command below to build:

   gcc -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS5 -DHAVE_READLINE shell.c sqlite3.c -lpthread -ldl -lm -lreadline -lncurses -o sqlite3

Note: You need -DHAVE_READLINE and -lreadline and -lncurses to get readline functionality.

Copy the sqlite3 binary to /usr/bin or add to your path.

Comment: This is the best answer. Note on Ubuntu 18.04 I first needed to run this: `sudo apt install libreadline-dev libncurses-dev`

Comment: Thanks, I added the sudo apt install steps for completeness purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to compile my own binary with this:

Download the "autoconf" source file from [SQLite Download page](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html).
Unzip and extract the tar, change to source directory.

Compile the source code with:

```
./configure --enable-readline
make
```

I am running on RedHat, so I had to run `yum install readline-devel` beforehand. This might be different on your machine.