# Strange keyboard when using sqlite shell on linux

Tags: linux, putty, readline

I use a linux box connected trough putty. Using it with bash, my keyboard performs well, but when I am using the sqlite shell (sqlite3 program) my keys get crazy:

```
del=^[[3~
up=^[[A
left=^[[D
right=^[[C
down=^[[B
```

here is my env (the relevant part):

```
TERM=linux
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHLVL=1
INPUTRC=/etc/inputrc
```

I would like to use my keys normally on sqlite, as I do on windows.

my inputrc:

```
# do not bell on tab-completion
#set bell-style none

set meta-flag on
set input-meta on
set convert-meta off
set output-meta on

# Completed names which are symbolic links to
# directories have a slash appended.
set mark-symlinked-directories on

$if mode=emacs

# for linux console and RH/Debian xterm
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line
"\e[5~": beginning-of-history
"\e[6~": end-of-history
"\e[3~": delete-char
"\e[2~": quoted-insert
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word

# for rxvt
"\e[8~": end-of-line

# for non RH/Debian xterm, can't hurt for RH/DEbian xterm
"\eOH": beginning-of-line
"\eOF": end-of-line

# for freebsd console
"\e[H": beginning-of-line
"\e[F": end-of-line
$endif
```

Comment: If NixOS, use `sqlite-interactive`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(FYI: those are the normal sequences generated by those keys on most terminals, it's up to a terminal or program/library to interpret them. You can show this on a working terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> then pressing <kbd>End</kbd> or other non-character key, where ctrl-V sets the next keypress to be treated literally.)

Seems like your `sqlite3` binary is not using `readline`, or the readline configuration (`inputrc`) is broken (less likely if `bash` is working ok though).

You may be able to confirm/deny if readline is being used with the following, replace `which sqlite3` with the full path if it's not in your `PATH`.

```
ldd `which sqlite3`
```

If you see `libreadline.so` or similar, then it *should* work, so check your `INPUTRC` environment variable, `~/.inputrc` and `/etc/inputrc`. 
There's a *slim* chance it's statically linked (`libreadline.a`), to check try:

```
strings -a `which sqlite3`| grep -i inputrc
```

If the strings `INPUTRC`, `~/.inputrc` or `/etc/inputrc` are present it looks like readline was statically linked, and should work.

(At best you can only get some basic version and compile information (`pragma compile_options`, if supported) from `sqlite3`, but not the full set of features, which is why we need to go poking at the binary.)

If neither `ldd` nor `strings` indicate readline, then it's almost certain that the binary does not have support.

Otherwise check this answer: [SQLite with readline support on Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/82408/sqlite-with-readline-support-on-ubuntu)

If you don't have readline support in your `sqlite3` binary you can *wrap* it using one of:

```
rlwrap sqlite3
socat READLINE EXEC:"sqlite3"
```

Both let you specify a history file on the command line.

You can also check your `bash` readline bindings, just to make sure that readline is working and configured as expected:

```
bind -p | egrep '\[[ABCD3].?":'
```

On my system (running `bash-3.x` within an `rxvt`) I get:

```
"\M-[3~": delete-char
"\M-[D": backward-char
"\M-[C": forward-char
"\M-[B": next-history
"\M-[A": previous-history
```

`\M` is "meta", which is equivalent to *escape*, so where you see "`\M-`" a "`\e`" should work too. When printed, *escape* is represented as `^[` (control-[).

Comment: I added my inputrc, if you could take a look to exclude this possibility

Comment: and my ldd of sqlite does not show libreadline

Comment: It *probably* doesn't have realdine support then, either upgrade your package (check compatibility issues if you have to upgrade version), or use `rlwrap` as a workaround. Answer updated.

Comment: My binary is not statically linked, and also my bind output is like yours. However, I don't have either rlwrap or socat in my install, and I don't have root access to install those.

Comment: Thanks, it was super helpful. I was using sqlite3 as provided by platform-tools for android on linux. This sqlite3 was not compiled with libreadline.so . After installing this package from ubuntu default repo, it's working fine.